# Ubuntu reinstall

Tags: partitioning, 14.04, system-installation, uninstall, restart

I recently really messed up on Ubuntu along with I've had problems with upgrading to 14.04 and I want to get rid of my windows side, I'm using dual boot. I want to pretty much just  get rid of the windows partition and get rid of Ubuntu 14.04 and revert back to 13.10. Hour would you go about doing that?

I understand how to if no Ubuntu is on the computer, but what about my situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install from the 13.10 media (which is supported until [July](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)); and select "[Use Entire Disk]" -

[image: Use entire disk]

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Now, where do I do that? On boot? On bootloader, from image/iso? I'm assuming second, but just want to make sure I'm correct

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13 From the installation media. Either DVD or USB.

Answer (score 0):

case that you **care** about data
You can burn a dvd with the ubuntu you like to have(13.04 I guess) and make a manual partitioning and you format and mount /(root) to 13.04 you mount but don't format the home partition , and you can format and mount the windows partition to xt4(and some for swap) and also use that personal linux space .

case that you **do not care** about data
 If you don't care about your data(home folder) , clear everything in manual partitioning and do 10-30 GB for /(root) 13.04 , swap for your memory and the rest home folder . There are some excellent guides for partitioning , it does seems intimidating at first , but it really isn't . I hope it answers fairly .